# Is it necessary to validate the same schema with joi and mongoose for prevent unvalidated data insert?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

my question is if need double validation whit joi and mongoose for prevent unvalidated data insert,  or if is´t inecesary and only make me losing performance?
I want to prevent that there may be a bug with the validation of joi,
if that happened the unvalidated data would be inserted in MongoDb.
How is the best pratices to this?

My Code:

Product.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const model = mongoose.model;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({

name: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 50,
    required: true,
    validate: [{
            validator: async name => await Product.where({ name }).countDocuments() === 0,
            message: ({ value }) => `El nombre del producto: ${value} ya esta cogido.` // TODO: security
        },
        {
            validator: async function(value) {
                const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ\s]{3,48}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}$/;
                return await regex.test(value);

            },
            message: 'solo letras y numeros, sin espacio al principio y al final' // TODO: security
        },
    ]
},

description: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 30,
    maxlength: 250,
    required: true,
    validate: {
        validator: async function(value) {
            const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ\s]{28,248}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}$/;
            return await regex.test(value)
        },
        message: 'solo letras y numeros, sin espacio al principio y al final' // TODO: security
    }
},

shortDescription: {
    type: String,
    minlength: 20,
    maxlength: 100,
    required: true,
    validate: {
        validator: async function(value) {
            const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ\s]{18,98}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}$/;
            return await regex.test(value)
        },
        message: 'solo letras y numeros, sin espacio al principio y al final' // TODO: security
    }
},

tags: [{
    type: String,
    requirer: true,
    validate: {
        validator: async function(value) {
            const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ\s]{3,98}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}$/;
            return await ((value && value.length > 4) && (regex.test(value)));
        },
        message: 'El producto tiene que tener como minimo un tag y cada tag min 5 caracteres solo letras y numeros, sin espacio al principio y al final.' // TODO: security
    }
}],

price: {
    type: Number,
    min: 30,
    required: true,
    validate: {

        validator: async val => await (

            val.isInteger && val >= 30
        ),
        message: ({ value }) => `El precio del producto: ${value} es invalido, tiene que ser positivo y mayor o igual a 30` // TODO: security
    }
},

create_At: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});


const Product = model('Product', ProductSchema);

exports.Product = Product;
```

ProductJoiValidation:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const nameSchema = Joi.string().min(5).max(50).regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ\s]{3,48}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}$/).label("Nombre del producto").options({
    language: {
        string: {
            regex: {
                base: "El nombre del producto no puede contener espacios ni al principio ni al final, solo caracteres alfanumericos"
            }
        }
    }
});

const descriptionSchema = Joi.string().min(30).max(250).regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ\s]{28,248}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}$/).label("Descripcion del producto").options({
    language: {
        string: {
            regex: {
                base: "La descripcion del producto no puede contener espacios ni al principio ni al final, solo caracteres alfanumericos"
            }
        }
    }
});

const shortDescriptionSchema = Joi.string().min(20).max(100).regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ\s]{18,98}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}$/).label("Descripcion corta del producto").options({
    language: {
        string: {
            regex: {
                base: "La descripcion del producto no puede contener espacios ni al principio ni al final, solo caracteres alfanumericos"
            }
        }
    }
});

const tagsSchema = Joi.array().items(Joi.string().min(5).regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ\s]{3,98}[a-zA-Z0-9ÁÉÍÓÚñáéíóúÑ]{1}$/)).min(1).label("tags").options({
    language: {
        string: {
            regex: {
                base: "Los tags del producto no puede contener espacios ni al principio ni al final, solo caracteres alfanumericos"
            }
        }
    }
});

const priceSchema = Joi.number().integer().positive().min(30);


const createProductSchema = Joi.object().keys({

    name: nameSchema.required(),
    description: descriptionSchema.required(),
    shortDescription: shortDescriptionSchema.required(),   
    tags: tagsSchema.required(),      
    price: priceSchema.required()

});

function validateCreateProduct(createProduct) {

    return Joi.validate(createProduct, createProductSchema, { abortEarly: false });
};

module.exports = {
    validateCreateProduct    
}
```

I want to prevent that there may be a bug with the validation of joi,
if that happened the unvalidated data would be inserted in MongoDb.

What is the best here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the proper JOI functions to validate your data. If you use, the standard is to use the middle-ware https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-joi-validation that will throw an error and won't execute the code in the controller. And don't do the validation in the endpoint handler, use a middleware, otherwise things can get messy! The great thing is that you just need to pass your JOI object and the package will take care of the response.

Comment: thanks, I've tried it and it works. But I have a question about how to handle the custom error of the middleware I have looked at the documentation and doing it in the way that is in the example and when the error is not from this middleware ,  isJoi undefined. 
How should I handle it?

Comment: You could add a try and catch in the middleware and in the middleware in the catch, return response.reply(5XX), where 5XX is the error code of your choice. Also, check the API documentation: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v14.3.1/API.md. If `error.isJoi` is undefined, it could mean that you are not doing your JOI verification correctly.

Comment: thanks for all the help. I was able to make it work by changing only the way to acess the mistake:
 if (err.error.isJoi) for this if ("error" in err && "isJoi" in err.error && err.error.isJoi === true), if not when the error wasing  different from the validation Joi ,was surpriseded that the property isJoi undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Joigoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joigoose). You create a Joi Schema and pass it to Mongoose like:

```
new Mongoose.Schema(Joigoose.convert(joiUserSchema));
```

I have been using it for a while with no problems.

Comment: how to have Mongoose Schema in controller ? Juanmad